# formatting with bash and column command line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the following file

```
100843      stars n30   2012-03-08  spartanico83
    stars n50   2009-11-28  babepy
    stars n05   2009-03-09  sandfox
    stars n20   2014-01-17  yeuce
```

My aim is to have that:

```
100843      stars n30   2012-03-08  spartanico83
            stars n50   2009-11-28  babepy
            stars n05   2009-03-09  sandfox
            stars n20   2014-01-17  yeuce
```

I have tried to use `column -t` as a command line but it gives me that

```
100843     stars n30   2012-03-08  spartanico83
stars n50  2009-11-28  babepy
stars n05  2009-03-09  sandfox
stars n20  2014-01-17  yeuce
```

Should I use a combination of `awk` and `sed` as well?

Thanks

Comment: No combination needed, just use `awk`.

Comment: I'm having a look at `awk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a tab with sed:

```
sed 's/^\([ ]*stars\)/\t\1/' input
```

or use sed/column for a more robust solution:

```
sed 's/^\([ \t]*stars\)/@\1/' input | column -t | sed 's/^@/ /'
```

Comment: However, is there nothing simplier? I'm asking because I truly thought that dealing with the options of `column` would be enough.

Comment: There might be something simpler but column seems to ignore the leading whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done just using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^ +/            /'
```

If the line begins with spaces, replace the initial spaces with 12 spaces.

Comment: Indeed, Jotne. It seems the copy and paste from my file to stackoverflow dashboard changed something ...

If I'm pasting the content of my file in my cygwin env, Barmar's solution is working a treat.

Apologies, Barmar.